# Netbeans, Darcula not working

Tags: java, netbeans

**I have the following problem with me IDE.**

I installed netbeans and proper plugin to it which is called **darcula**. It should change the color of the whole editor, toolbars and so on. Surprisingly it changes only the view of the place of code edition. Does annybody has some solution to it.

**The version of netbeans is 8.2 and OS is Ubuntu 16.04.**

[image: Problem with darcula plugin]

Comment: Did you restart the ide?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: I think you have instead perhaps done a quick switch theme, or set it in the the Editor | Colors & Fonts as supposed to Settings/Preferences | Appearance | Theme.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to `Tools -> Options -> Appearance -> Look and feel` and select preferred look and feel: Darcula option from the dropdown. Restart the IDE and it should work

[image]